# Python GEKKO: Value of parameter changes while solving the model

Tags: python-3.x, gekko

I face the following problem with GEKKO: some parameters (.Param) are changing (others not) when solving a model and I cannot determine why.

Background: I am currently trying to translate code from EViews (see [gennaro.zezza.it](https://gennaro.zezza.it/software/eviews/v6/gl03sim_a.prg)) to python. I use GEKKO to simulate a system consisting out of 11 equations (for now). I do want to use parameters (instead of constants which seem to work perfectly fine) as I need to ('exogenously') change their value over time (and thus need an array).

Example: In the following example, an 'economic system' reacts to new government expenditures. Here, I particularly face problems with "m.alpha1" and "m.alpha2" - if they are introduced as ".Param" their value will change to 1.0 (instead of 0.6 and 0.4) when solving the model. How can I stop GEKKO from doing this? (Again, I want to be able to change, e.g., alpha1 to 0.7 after time x. E.g., lower and upper bounds won't help here.)

Thanks for your help!!

Code:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import plotly.graph_objects as go

# Initialize model
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
tstart = 1945
tend = 2000
tdur = tend-tstart+1
m.time = np.linspace(0, tend-tstart, tdur)

# Model parameters
m.t = m.Param(value=m.time)

# Exogenous parameters
alpha1_ex = 0.6
alpha2_ex = 0.4
theta_ex = 0.2
w_ex = 1

# -as .Const
m.alpha1 = m.Const(value=alpha1_ex, name='Propensity to consume out of income')
m.alpha2 = m.Const(value=alpha2_ex, name='Propensity to consume out of wealth')
#m.theta = m.Const(value=theta_ex, name='Tax rate')
#m.w = m.Const(value=w_ex, name='Wage rate')

# -as .Param: issues with alpha1 & alpha2
#m.alpha1 = m.Param(value=np.full(tdur,alpha1_ex), name='Propensity to consume out of income')
#m.alpha2 = m.Param(value=np.full(tdur,alpha2_ex), name='Propensity to consume out of wealth')
m.theta = m.Param(value=np.full(tdur,theta_ex), name='Tax rate')
m.w = m.Param(value=np.ones(tdur), name='Wage rate')

# no issues with g_d
m.g_d = m.Param(value=np.zeros(tdur), name='Government goods, demand')
m.g_d[1:] = 20

# Endogenous variables
m.c_d = m.Var(value=0, name='Consumption goods demand by households')
m.c_s = m.Var(value=0, name='Consumption goods supply')
m.g_s = m.Var(value=0, name='Government goods, supply')
m.h_h = m.Var(value=0, name='Cash money held by households')
m.h_s = m.Var(value=0, name='Cash money supplied by government')
m.n_d = m.Var(value=0, name='Demand for labor')
m.n_s = m.Var(value=0, name='Supply for labor')
m.t_d = m.Var(value=0, name='Taxes, "demand"')
m.t_s = m.Var(value=0, name='Taxes, "supply"')
m.y = m.Var(value=0, name='Income (=GDP)')
m.yd = m.Var(value=0, name='Disposable income of households')

# Lag variables
m.h_h_lag = m.Var(value=0, name='Cash money held by households (t-1)')
m.delay(m.h_h,m.h_h_lag,1) # m.h_h_lag = m.h_h(t-1)
m.h_s_lag = m.Var(value=0, name='Cash money supplied by government (t-1)')
m.delay(m.h_s,m.h_s_lag,1)

# Equations
m.Equation(m.c_s == m.c_d)
m.Equation(m.g_s == m.g_d)
m.Equation(m.t_s == m.t_d)
m.Equation(m.n_s == m.n_d)
m.Equation(m.yd == m.w*m.n_s - m.t_s)
m.Equation(m.t_d == m.theta*m.w*m.n_s)
m.Equation(m.c_d == m.alpha1*m.yd + m.alpha2*m.h_h_lag)
m.Equation(m.h_s == m.h_s_lag + m.g_d - m.t_d)
m.Equation(m.h_h == m.h_h_lag + m.yd - m.c_d)
m.Equation(m.y == m.c_s + m.g_s)
m.Equation(m.n_d == m.y/m.w)

# Solve
m.options.IMODE = 4
m.solve(disp=False)

print("Alpha1 = ", m.alpha1.value)
print("Alpha2 = ", m.alpha2.value)
print("Theta = ", m.theta.value)
print("w = ", m.w.value)

# Plot results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2, 2, sharex=True, figsize=(8, 7))
fig.canvas.manager.set_window_title('Figures Chapter 3')
fig.suptitle('SIM Model - basic')
x_major_ticks = np.arange(0,tdur,5)

axes[0,0].plot(m.time, m.g_d.value, '-', color='black', linewidth=1)
axes[0,0].legend([m.g_d.name],loc=4,fontsize=7)
axes[0,0].grid()
axes[0,0].set_xticks(x_major_ticks)

axes[1,0].plot(m.time, m.y.value, '-', color='red', linewidth=1)
axes[1,0].legend([m.y.name],loc=4,fontsize=7)
axes[1,0].grid()
axes[1,0].set_xlabel('Time (years)')
axes[1,0].set_xticks(x_major_ticks)

axes[0,1].plot(m.time, m.c_d.value, '-', color='blue', linewidth=0.75)
axes[0,1].plot(m.time, m.yd.value, '-', color='green', linewidth=0.75)
axes[0,1].legend([m.c_d.name,m.yd.name],loc=4,fontsize=7)
axes[0,1].grid()
axes[0,1].set_xticks(x_major_ticks)

ln1 = axes[1,1].plot(m.time, m.h_h.value, '-', color='purple', linewidth=0.75)
axes[1,1].tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='purple')
ax2 = axes[1,1].twinx()
ln2 = ax2.plot(m.time, [a_i - b_i for a_i, b_i in zip(m.h_h, m.h_h_lag)], '-', color='orange', linewidth=0.75)
ax2.tick_params(axis='y', labelcolor='orange')
lns = ln1+ln2
axes[1,1].legend(lns,[m.h_h.name,'Household savings'],loc=4,fontsize=7)
axes[1,1].grid()
axes[1,1].set_xticks(x_major_ticks)
axes[1,1].set_xlabel('Time (years)')

plt.show()
```

Output #1: with m.alpha1 and m.alpha2 as .const

```
Alpha1 =  0.6
Alpha2 =  0.4
Theta =  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
w =  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Output #2: with m.alpha1 as .param

```
Alpha1 =  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
Alpha2 =  0.4
Theta =  [0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
w =  [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the name of the variable `name='Propensity to consume out of income'` is over 25 characters long.

```py
m.alpha1 = m.Param(value=np.full(tdur,alpha1_ex), name='Propensity to consume out of income')
m.alpha2 = m.Param(value=np.full(tdur,alpha2_ex), name='Propensity to consume out of wealth')
```

The model file is produced correctly (`gk_model0.apm`) but the data file (`gk_model0.csv`) header is truncated to 25 characters. The files are accessible with `m.open_folder()`. The bug is in this line of `gk_write_files.py` where numbers are output as strings of length 25.

```py
np.savetxt(os.path.join(self._path,file_name), csv_data.T, delimiter=",", fmt='%1.25s')
```

I've added this as a [bug report with tracking on GitHub](https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/issues/118). One work-around is to use shorter variable names or leave off the variable names.

```py
m.alpha1 = m.Param(value=np.full(tdur,alpha1_ex)) # Propensity to consume out of income
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the quick reply, John. Highly appreciated.

Comment: I uploaded the bug fix to the GitHub repository and included a note in the CHANGELOG.